# почему style.backgroundColor не работает

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var blue = document.getElementsByClassName('cell');
alert(blue[0]);
alert(blue[0].style.backgroundColor)
```

```css
.cell {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell"></div>
```

или как узнать фоновый цвет?

Comment: нашол способ        window.getComputedStyle( document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[0] ,null).getPropertyValue('background-color')       но это слишком длинный и не очень понятный

Comment: Вполне понятный, только не помешает его сократить до `getComputedStyle(blue[0]).backgroundColor`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё работает. Но в `style` есть только то и ровно то, что прописано непосредственно в атрибуте:

```js
var blue = document.getElementsByClassName('cell')[0]

console.log(blue.style.backgroundColor) // blue
console.log(getComputedStyle(blue).backgroundColor) // red
```

```css
.cell {
  background-color: red !important;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell" style="background-color:blue"></div>
```

Comment: те blue.style.backgroundColor берет цвет не с css,   а с  атрибута тега?

Comment: @TigranVardanyan, да. И берёт оттуда, и записывает туда же. Это inline-стиль.