# JavaScript игнорирует условие if и выдает сразу конечный результат

Tags: javascript

Мини игра по поиску предметов, при нажатии на искомый предмет он исчезает "display: none".  После того как все искомые предметы найдены, блок с игрой исчезает и появляется другой блок.
Проблема в том что после записи кода он сразу исполняет исчезновение основного блока с игрой игнорируя условия.  Что я делаю не так? 
[проект на gitHub](https://github.com/Olegm23/minigame)
Использую только JavaScript без JQuery

```
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div id="begin" class="beginer"> <img class="bg" src="img/bg_ho.png" alt="bg">
        <div class="tutorial1"><img class="tutorial" src="img/Tutorial1.png" alt="tutorial">
            <p class="pulsate">Find all the
                <br>hidden objects!</p>
        </div>
        <a href="#one" id="ap"> <img class="apple" id="apple" src="img/apple.png" alt="apple"> </a>
        <a href="#two" id="sh"> <img class="shoe" id="shoe" src="img/shoe.png" alt="shoes"> </a>
        <a href="#three" id="bk"> <img class="book" id="book" src="img/book.png" alt="book"> </a>
        <a href="#for" id="pr"> <img class="purse" id="purse" src="img/purse.png" alt="apple"> </a>
        <div class="bottom"><img class="bottom" src="img/ho_gui.png" alt="bottom">
            <div class="text">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <h1 id="one">Apple</h1></li>
                    <li>
                        <h1 id="two">Shoe</h1></li>
                    <li>
                        <h1 id="three">Book</h1></li>
                    <li>
                        <h1 id="for">Purse</h1></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="fs" class="finish"> <img class="blur" src="img/bg_blur.png" alt="bg"> </div>
</div>
<script>
    //loss apple
    document.getElementById('ap').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('apple').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('one').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
        //loss shoe
    document.getElementById('sh').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('shoe').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('two').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
        //loss book
    document.getElementById('bk').onclick = function () {
            document.getElementById('book').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('three').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
        }
        //loss purse
    document.getElementById('pr').onclick = function () {
        document.getElementById('purse').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('for').style.textDecoration = 'line-through';
    }
</script>
<script>
    if (document.getElementById('apple').style.display = 'none' && document.getElementById('shoe').style.display = 'none' && document.getElementById('book').style.display = 'none' && document.getElementById('purse').style.display = 'none') {
        document.getElementById('begin').style.display = 'none';
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если скрипт запускается сразу после открытия окна, его нужно обернуть в document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded"), иначе скрипт выполнится до завершения загрузки страницы. Событие "DOMContentLoaded" возникает после завершения загрузки и позволяет обращаться к DOM-элементам без боязни их не найти.

И как сказали выше

"=" - [оператор присваивания](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Assignment_Operators)

"===" - [оператор строгого равенства](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/%D0%9E%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B_%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)

При использовании if... вам нужно сравнивать значения, и первый оператор тут не подойдет

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
   if (document.getElementById('apple').style.display === 'none' && 
       document.getElementById('shoe').style.display === 'none' && 
       document.getElementById('book').style.display === 'none' && 
       document.getElementById('purse').style.display === 'none') {

      document.getElementById('begin').style.display = 'none';
   }
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Потому что надо не `=`, а `===`.

Comment: на каком участке кода изменить?

Comment: @ОлегМорковкин в условии if... `...style.display = 'none'` заменить на `...style.display === 'none'`

Comment: не помогло, ни чего не выполняется

Comment: ну опечатка же, или дубликат на худой конец

Comment: @Grundy, ну так дубликать, а мне лень искать...

Comment: лучше как опечатку закрой. Опечатка опечатка

Comment: @Grundy, точно не опечатка - даже по комментам под ответом видно.

Comment: @ОлегМорковкин, скорее всего не выполняется потому что https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/905577/178988